# why regex is not working properly as expected (select text after domain)?

Tags: regex, kubernetes

I am trying to write few regex . I am testing my regex on below link
https://www.regextester.com/

**Case 1**

1.regex: **/flow**

**Testing string** : https://example.com/flow

**Testing result** : correct same as expected (selected after domain)
[image]

**case 2**

1. **/_next/.***

**Testing string**: https://example.com/_next/static/css/96c1d677121f4c49.css

**Testing result** : correct same as expected (selected after domain)
[image]

**Case 3**:

2. regex: **/(.+.(css|js))**
   **Testing string**: https://example.com/96c1d677121f4c49.css

**Testing result** : NOT correct(it is selecting everything domain + match element)

[image]

**Expected output** : ONLY select **"96c1d677121f4c49.css"** NOT domain

any way to fix this bug ?

Comment: You probably just want `[^\/]*\.css` or `[^\/]+\.css`. In a more broader case, `[^\/#?]*\.css` or even ``[^\/#?]+\.css(?![^\/?#])``

Comment: That backslash you see in the screenshots are part of the regex literal `/ /` syntax. It's not part of the regex characters

Comment: Why are you trying to use regular expressions to parse URLs? There's a built-in URL API...

Comment: @caTS sometimes it is required in config files (I'm assuming this because they have added the kubernetes tag)

Comment: @adiga yes I need in kubernetes.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `[^\/#?]+\.css(?![^\/?#])` is working for `.css` files what about `.js`files ? .. or in other words how we support for `.js` files also

Comment: I explained how in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74318378/3832970).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
[^\/#?]+\.(?:css|js)(?![^\/?#])
```

*Details*:

- `[^\/#?]+` - one or more chars other than `/`, `?` and `#`
- `\.` - a literal dot
- `(?:css|js)` - `css` or `js`
- `(?![^\/?#])` - a negative lookahead that requires end of string or a `/`, `?` or `#` char immediately to the right of the current location.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Fv1SCK/1).

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use javascript built in Url object tooling to extract everything you need including pathname (/flow), or parameters. See more here : https://dmitripavlutin.com/parse-url-javascript/

Hope this helps you find a way to properly parse your urls

Answer (score 0):

There's a built-in [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) API to help you parse URLs:

```js
const urls = [
  "https://example.com/flow",
  "https://example.com/_next/static/css/96c1d677121f4c49.css",
  "https://example.com/96c1d677121f4c49.css",
];

for (const string of urls) {
    const url = new URL(string);
    // slice to get rid of leading '/'
    console.log(url.pathname.slice(1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the positive lookbehind technique, to search for the slash before the file `(?<=\/)\w*\.(css|js)`.

1. `(?<=\/)` check for a slash before the target text.
2. `\w*` any number of word character
3. `\.` for dot
4. `(css|js)` for css or js extension.

[FOR TEST](https://regex101.com/r/3udCll/1)